# Expressing complex numbers in exponential form

Tags: complex-numbers, exponential-function

I do not know why I am having so many issues with complex numbers. I am basically trying to teach myself, but keep doubting myself and getting very frustrated. I've no way of checking my answers so I'm just lost. So I want to write the following in polar form $re^{i\theta}$ (although I thought that was called exponential form?) and $-\pi < \theta \leq \pi$.

My first question is expressing $(\cos(\frac{2\pi}{9}) + i\sin(\frac{2\pi}{9}))^3$. Using De Moivre, this is $$\cos(\frac{2\pi}{3}) + i\sin(\frac{2\pi}{3})$$ so it is $e^{i(\frac{2\pi}{3})}$ yes?

My next one is to express $\frac{2+2i}{-\sqrt{3} +i}$. So my attempt is to multiply by the complex conjugate and we get that this is $\frac{-\sqrt{3} +1}{2} + i\frac{-1 - \sqrt{3}}{2}$. Find $r$ which is the modulus which is $\sqrt2$ and $\theta$ is just something I cannot seem to find. I know if $z = a+ib$ then $\theta = \tan^{-1}(\frac{b}{a})$ but I'm stuck even with the $(\frac{b}{a})$ and am confusing myself of what quadrant to look in.

Lastly, I have no idea how to express the next one which is $\frac{4i}{3e^{(4+i)}}$.

Any help and direction at all is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Yes, $\left(\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}9\right)+i\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}9\right)\right)^3=\left(\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}3\right)+i\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}3\right)\right)$.
- Note that$$\frac{2+2i}{-\sqrt3+i}=\frac{1+i}{-\frac{\sqrt3}2+\frac12i}.$$Furthermore, $1+i=\sqrt2\left(\cos\left(\frac{\pi}4\right)+i\sin\left(\frac{\pi}4\right)\right)$ and $-\frac{\sqrt3}2+\frac12i=\cos\left(\frac{5\pi}6\right)+i\sin\left(\frac{5\pi}6\right)$. So, the quotient is equal to$$\sqrt2\left(\cos\left(\frac\pi4-\frac{5\pi}6\right)+i\sin\left(\frac\pi4-\frac{5\pi}6\right)\right)=\sqrt2\left(\cos\left(-\frac{7\pi}{12}\right)+i\sin\left(-\frac{7\pi}{12}\right)\right).$$
- Note that$$\frac{4i}{3e^{4+i}}=\frac43\times\frac{e^{\frac{\pi i}2}}{e^{4+i}}=\frac43e^{-4+\frac{\pi i}2-i}.$$

Comment: No, I am sorry. I am grateful for your help so far but I honestly have no idea where to go from there. I see/know how you rewrote the two complex numbers above but I do not know why or see how it helps in either  case.

Comment: @moony I've edited my answer. Is it clear now?

Comment: Thank you, a lot clearer. But in the answer to the quotient, why are you subtracting $\frac{\pi}{6}$ from $\frac{\pi}{4}?$ Is there a rule I am missing? Also, I finally see now for the last bit you just used properties of indices, so $r = \frac{4}{3}$ and $\theta$ is a bit confusing. I can't factor out the i to get it in the form $e^{i\theta}$. I do not know what to do here.

Comment: @moony I'm using the fact that $\exp(x)/\exp(y)=\exp(x-y)$.

Comment: Ok so why are you not subtracting $\frac{5\pi}{6}$ rather than $\frac{\pi}{6}$?

Comment: @moony It was an error. I've edited my answer.

Comment: OK I get it now. Thank you. Finally, can I just get a little more direction on the last part of the last answer you have above. I cannot factor out i so cannot work out what $\theta$ is?

Comment: @moony There is no $\theta$ in my answer.

Comment: I know but I want to get it in the form $re^{i\theta}$. Right now it seems like it is in the form $re^{-4+ \frac{i\pi}{2} - i}$ and I see no way of getting it in the correct form?

Comment: @moony $$\frac43e^{-4+\frac{i\pi}2-i}=\frac4{3e^4}e^{\left(\frac\pi2-1\right)i}.$$

Comment: Ahh ok so it doesn't matter that $r = \frac{4}{3e^4}$, i.e. that $e$ is involved in $r$ since $e$ is just a number. And $e^{-4 + \frac{i\pi}{2} -i}$ is the same thing as saying $e^{-4} * e ^{\frac{i\pi}{2} -i}$ and $e^{-4}$ is just $\frac{1}{e^4} ?$

Comment: Ok no wait, I've confused myself, is this saying then that $\theta = \frac{\pi}{2} - 1?$

Comment: @moony Yes, I am.

Comment: Ok, so that's the final answer so?

Comment: @moony No. You should say that $\theta=\frac\pi2-1$.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I meant for $\theta$ and that $r = \frac{4}{3e^4}$?

Comment: @moony My mistake. There is no difference.

Comment: Thank you so very much Jose Carlos Santos. You have been a great help and have been very patient and explained everything well. Thank you

Comment: @moony I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

You have $\frac {2+2i}{-\sqrt 3 + i}$ rather than rationalizing the denominator, and converting, convert numerator and denominator.

$2+2i = 2\sqrt2e^{\frac {\pi}{4}i}\\
-\sqrt 3 + i = 2e^{\frac {5\pi}{6}i}\\ 
\frac {2+2i}{-\sqrt 3 + i} = \sqrt 2\frac {e{\frac {\pi}{4}i}}{e{\frac {5\pi}{6}i}} = \sqrt2e^{(\frac {\pi}{4}i-\frac{5\pi}{6}i)}= \sqrt2e^{-\frac {7\pi}{12}i}$

Since you did get as far as:

$z = \frac {-\sqrt 3 + 1}{2} + \frac {-\sqrt 3 - 1}{2}i$

After doing it enough times in trig class I came to memorize $\cos \frac \pi{12} = \frac {\sqrt 6 + \sqrt 2}{4}, \sin \frac \pi{12} = \frac {\sqrt 6 - \sqrt 2}{4}$

Which might have helped.

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{2+2i}{-\sqrt{3} +i} =$

$\frac {(2+2i)(-\sqrt{3} -i)}{(-\sqrt{3} +i)(-\sqrt{3} -i)}=$

$\frac {(-2\sqrt{3} +2)- (2\sqrt 3+2)i}{3+1}=$

$\frac {-\sqrt3 + 1}2 -\frac{\sqrt 3 + 1}2i=$

$r(\cos \theta + i\sin \theta)$

So we need to solve for $r\cos \theta = \frac {-\sqrt3 + 1}2$ and $r\sin \theta =  -\frac{\sqrt 3 + 1}2$.

That's all.

We solve for $r$ by squaring and adding both terms:

$r^2\cos^2 \theta + r^2 \sin^2 \theta = (\frac {-\sqrt3 + 1}2)^2 + ( -\frac{\sqrt 3 + 1}2)^2$

$r^2(\cos^2 \theta + \sin^2 \theta) = \frac {3 - 2\sqrt 3 + 1}4 + \frac {3+2\sqrt 3 + 1}4$.

$r^2 = 1 - \frac {\sqrt 3}2 + 1+\frac {\sqrt 3}2$

$r^2 = 2$

$r = \sqrt 2$.

And we solve for $\theta$ by dividing both terms and taking the arctangent:

$\tan \theta = \frac {\sin\theta}{\cos\theta} = \frac {r*\sin\theta}{r*\cos\theta} = \frac {-\frac{\sqrt 3 + 1}2}{\frac {-\sqrt3 + 1}2}$

$=\frac {\sqrt 3 + 1}{-\sqrt3 + 1} =\frac {(\sqrt 3 + 1)(-\sqrt 3- 1}{(-\sqrt3 + 1)}=\frac {-4 - 2\sqrt 3}{2} = -2-\sqrt 3$

So $\theta = \arctan  -2-\sqrt 3= -\frac 5{12}\pi$

S $\frac{2+2i}{-\sqrt{3} +i} = \sqrt 2*e^{-\frac 5{12}\pi i}$.